# Ubuntu 20.04 server installation on VirtualBox with Windows 10 Shared folder permission issue

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, php, windows-10, nginx

I am trying to install Magento2.4 Open source on the following setup.

*VirtualBox 6.1 installed on Windows 10*

*Nginx server installed on the VirtualBox*

*Ubuntu 20.4 Server installed on the Virtualbox*

*Php 7.3.20*

To make the Windows folder shared on the VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 Server, I used following process.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348495/1616003

1)
sudo apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

2. Reboot the Virtual Machine
3. Make this shared folder auto mounted

   *mount -t vboxsf magento2_vm_folder /var/www/html*

   *echo "sudo mount -t vboxsf magento2_vm_folder /var/www/html" >> /home/mukesh/.profile*
4. sudo visudo

   mukesh ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount

The Windows folder is now accessible in the VirtualBox's Ubuntu server's */var/www/html*

Now I am trying to install Magento2.4 in the */var/www/html* directory. To do it I run following command

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

I get following error

*Plugin installation failed (include(/var/www/html/qa.magento.com/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/src/MagentoHackathon/Composer/Magento/Plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), rolling back*

**Note**:
When I perform all the above mentioned steps in Ubuntu Server 18.04 then everything works fine. It seems some permission issue.

So could some one help me understand if something has changed in the Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Even if I give 777 permission on /var/www/html folder the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that some folder under "/var/www/html/" does not have the 777 permission.

There are two ways of solving this, one by adding nginx to the vboxsf and the other by using mount options.

vboxsf group:

```
usermod -aG vboxsf nginx
```

Using /etc/fstab options:

```
magento2_vm_folder    /var/www/html     vboxsf    defaults,uid=<nginx uid>,gid=<nginx gid>,umask=0022    0    0
```

EDIT: If you're using PHP in FPM mode, you may need to substitute the nginx user for the PHP FPM user's info.

Comment: @Brain Turek How do it get <nginx gid> values?

Comment: For UID: id -u <username> (I'm not sure if it's "nginx" or "www-data")
For GID: id -g username